# What are the best chess blogs?

Tags: recommendations, chess-blog

I enjoy reading about chess and there is a number of blogs that I follow. And I do toy with the idea of starting a chess blog myself in a distant and uncertain future. So I want to tap your combined knowledge:

- What are the best chess blogs you know?
- What makes them so interesting?

(I know this is the kind of subjective question, stackexchange usually doesn't go for, but I think this could be a very worthwhile collection, possibly as community wiki.)

Answer (score 8):

For players under 1800 USCF/FIDE, [Dan Heisman's blog](http://www.chess.com/blog/danheisman) is an extremely helpful source. He has lots of information on:

- Thought process: how Hope Chess can cause losses
- Time Management: how to manage your time in order to be able to think as much as possible when the game gets complicated.
- Practical tips for different situations: when you're way ahead, it's a different game; when you're losing, complicate the position to try to get your opponent to make a mistake; when your opponent is in time pressure, don't blitz him, etc.
- Correcting misconceptions: player not recapturing because then he would get doubled pawns (safety is a 100, pawn structure is a 1), players loses because he didn't "see" something when in fact he didn't look out for it (thought process), player making a quick move in a critical position (hand-waving), Player playing a quick move because all moves look bad (acquiescing), Player rejecting move based on shallow or superficial analysis (quiescence error) . . . The list goes on, check out his blog!

Comment: I would like to further recommend this blog. As someone who is pretty terrible (no USCF/FIDE games to my name), his blog has really opened my eyes to some ideas I had never even previously considered. Implementing them in my own games of course is proving to be more challenging...

Comment: Agree.  Dan covers many topics that new players may not consider as part of chess improvement such as thinking process and time management

Answer (score 2):

- [TheChessMind](http://www.thechessmind.net) by Dennis Monokroussos. Pretty much the best alternative to the major chess news sites. Often a bit faster, commented games, interesting tidbits.
- [The Streatham Brixton Chess Blog](http://streathambrixtonchess.blogspot.de). Different writers from one club, write about vastly different topics. You'll get deeply researched articles about chess in art, chess politics, endgames, openings and and and …
- [Dana blogs chess](http://www.danamackenzie.com/blog/). A comparatively narrow view into the chess life of one enthusiastic amateur player. Often quite instructive.
- [GM Smerdons blog](http://www.davidsmerdon.com). Not that much chess and not particularly frequently updated, but a very strong player and good writer giving his opinion and writing about his experiences.

Edit: I'll add some discontinued blogs, because there is still great stuff to discover:

- [The Chessninja](http://www.chessninja.com/dailydirt/). Mig Greengard, journalist and Kasparov devotee, probably the most entertaining writer about chess, gives his take on current affairs.
- [The Kenilworthian](http://kenilworthian.blogspot.de). Chess blog by Michael Goeller. A lot of stuff about tricky openings.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Tim Krabbé's CHESS CURIOSITIES](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess/chess.html). It contains all sorts of interesting facts and stories related to chess. There are also many puzzles and interesting games, with comments, historical notes and curious details related to the games/problems/players. It is highly entertaining, instructive and well-written.

Majnu's blog is a great site for learning, especially for a beginner. In my opinion, Majnu is very talented in relating chess ideas in a clear, precise and easy-to-follow way. An excellent player and an excellent teacher, so his blog can hardly be anything else but excellent, as well.

Comment: There is a lot of good chess stuff on that web site, but the only part of it that is a blog is Krabbé's [Open chess diary](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary.htm). Although Tim Krabbé returned to it recently to mark the passing of Harry Goldsteen (d. 5 Jun 2021), he has unfortunately let it lie practically dormant for many uears.

Answer (score 1):

A few days back, I wrote an article called [Top 11 Chess Blogs You Love to Read](https://chessblogger.org/blog/best-chess-blogs/). I added 11 chess blogs for it. It will worth reading.

I will add two main blogs from that list to this answer and why they are good.

**Chess.com blog**: They publish around 100 posts per month. So it can be introduced as the most active chess blog. Most articles are written by grandmasters and international masters.

**The Chess World BLog**: The author of this blog started this blog when his rating was under 1200. But after 2 years his rating was more than 2200. So this blog will be very helpful for beginner chess players who have the plan to get a 2000 rating in just under 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

[chess.com blog](http://www.chess.com/blog/)  It is great blog with good few good articles written by chess masters (I read one for GM Hikaru [this one](http://www.chess.com/blog/Hikaru/us-champs))

Answer (score -1):

Also check out Greg Shahade's [blog](https://gregshahade.wordpress.com/) .

Comment: Can you tell us *why* we should do this? Or at least what kind of topics he writes about? The top three answers to this question are a good example.

Comment: Its a good blog - check it out. The dude is an IM and has interesting opinions. Bizzare downvoting of a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score -1):

My top two choices would be

- [Chess Daily News](https://chessdailynews.com/)
- [Begin Chess](http://www.beginchess.com)

Comment: That's only two :)

Comment: Can you tell us *why* we should read these blogs? Or at least what kind of topics he writes about? The top three answers to this question are a good example.